# Use length of listofitems inside whiledo not working

Tags: number, listofitems

I am trying to use the length of an listofitems item (see `foo`) inside a `whiledo`.
The loop shall be executed until the counter value reached the same value.

this is working:

```
\newcommand{\dummy}[1]{
    \setsepchar{,}
    \readlist*\foo{#1}
    \setcounter{cnt}{1}

    \whiledo{5>\value{cnt}}{
        \arabic{cnt} \\
        \stepcounter{cnt}
    }
}
```

But this **not** (undefined control sequence):

```
\newcommand{\dummy}[1]{
    \setsepchar{,}
    \readlist*\foo{#1}
    \setcounter{cnt}{1}

    \whiledo{\foolen>\value{cnt}}{
        \arabic{cnt} \\
        \stepcounter{cnt}
    }
}
```

Why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem making the construct work in the manner you provided.  Perhaps your undefined sequence was in not loading the `ifthen` package, which provides `\whiledo`.  However, I would recommend using the native construct of `listofitems`, which is that of a `\foreachitem` loop, as shown in the second sequence below.

In that way, neither the `ifthen` package nor the `cnt` counter is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,ifthen}
\newcounter{cnt}
\begin{document}
With the \verb|\whiledo| construct:

\newcommand{\dummy}[1]{
    \setsepchar{,}
    \readlist*\foo{#1}
    \setcounter{cnt}{1}

    \whiledo{\foolen>\value{cnt}}{% OR \whiledo{\listlen\foo[]>\value{cnt}}
        \arabic{cnt} \\
        \stepcounter{cnt}
    }
}

\dummy{a,b,c,d,e}

With the \verb|\foreachitem| construct:

\renewcommand{\dummy}[1]{
    \setsepchar{,}
    \readlist*\foo{#1}

    \foreachitem\z\in\foo{%
      \ifnum\zcnt<\listlen\foo[]\relax\zcnt\\\fi
    }
}

\dummy{a,b,c,d,e}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact it is working. The problem why I see errors is (I guess) I am using this command within tabularx context.

Comment: @PIC-Nico This is why providing a full working Minimum Working Example (MWE) is essential for the questioner (OP).  It shows the problem *in the context* in which it arose.